# What is cascading in hibernate if i give like this cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.ALL

Tags: hibernate

I am not understanding below cascade. 
Please someone can elobrate it {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.ALL} and when to use which cascade? 
As per my understanding, we are using it for association. If we are going to delete parent table, do we have to delete child table first?
Please, could someone correct me?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-cascade

Comment: Hi sir give me a some other tutorial so i am new to hibernate this documents looks high level